# How to filter out sections of an array with subsections in PHP?

Tags: php

I am having trouble figuring out how I can filter/sort these arrays where it shows section 1 then all the subsection (1,2,3,...) of section 1, without section 1 repeating.

Next it will loop to section 2 then all the subsection (1,2,3,...) of section 2, without section 2 repeating.

There has to be an if statement or something to help prevent the sections from showing for every single subsection.

```
SELECT  section, subsection
FROM    table
WHERE   id = :id
ORDER BY section, subsection
```

output  section, = 1

then show only the subsection of section 1 = 1,2,3

then output section, =2

then show only the subsection of section 2 = 1,2,3,4

sample of an array output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            section, => 1
            [0] => 1
            subsection=> 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            section, => 1
            [0] => 1
            subsection=> 2
            [1] => 2

        )
)
```

I was trying this for a loop, but can't figure out how to stop the section from duplicating:

```
<?php 
    echo    "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
            $numrows = count($tabs);
            for ($i =0; $i < $numrows; $i++){
                $sectionnumrows = count($tabs[$i]['section']);
                echo $tabs[$i]['section'].","; // don't want this to repeat, only show once

                for ($j=0; $j < $sectionnumrows; $j++){     

                    $subsectionnumrows = count($tabs[$i]['subsection']);
                    for ($k=0; $k < $sectionnumrows; $k++){ 

                        if([$i]['section'] == $j){
                                echo "subsection ".$tabs[$i]['subsection']."<br>";
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
    echo    "</div>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your query and you`ll get only unique sections and all the subsection will be concated-if I understand what you want.

```
SELECT  section, GROUP_CONCAT(subsection) as subsection
FROM    table
WHERE   id = :id
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY section, subsection
```

Comment: The only problem with testing this is that this method stops at section 1.

Comment: @user7480839 Since you only have 2 sections,change  < in your loop(s) t to <=

Comment: There will be some with 3 or more sections...  I will try that out. :)

Comment: $result = explode(',', $tabs[$i]['subsection']); // to break it apart.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mihai answer:

```
    $numrows = count($tabs);
        for ($i =0; $i < $numrows; $i++){
            echo "section" . $tabs[$i]['section'].",";
            $result = explode(',', $tabs[$i]['subsection']); // $row['subsection'] contains string 1,2,3.. .etc
            foreach($result as $row){
                echo "<br> subsection ".$row ;
            }
        }
```

Here is an example if you have 2 GROUP_CONCAT subsections:

```
SELECT  section, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(subsection) as subsection1,
        GROUP_CONCAT(subsection2) as subsection2
FROM    table
WHERE   id = :id
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY section, subsection

$combined = array_combine($subsection1 , $subsection2);

foreach ($combined as $subsection1 => $subsection2){
    echo "$subsection1 => $subsection2";
}
```